# Limiting the number of products in wishlist — Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2, wishlist

In Magento 2.2, is there any possible way, through the admin panel, or through the custom theme that we can limit the number of each wish-listed product to 1?

To be more clear; so when the "add to wishlist" button is clicked multiple times, the item will be added to wishlist multiple times, is there any way to "not" allow each individual item being added to wishlist more than once?

Please let me know if it is not yet clear so I provide more description.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I understand you don't want write code, right?

Comment: Not really, I am ok writing code. I already made a custom theme for the project, the truth is that I am relatively new to Magento, I am not able to create a custom module from scratch but I have some general ideas on how to override PHTML files, PHP classes, CCS and JS files.

Comment: You need to create plugin for this class: Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add which located at magento_root/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Controller/Index/Add.php

Helpful links:
http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/
http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/